# MySQL Complex Joining

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables (vehicles, available_colors) as following,

### vehicles

```
id  vehicle_name
--  ------------
1   Honda Dio
2   Yamaha FZ
3   RE Classic 350
```

### available_colors

```
id  vehicle_id  color
--  ----------  ----
1   1           Red
2   1           Yello
3   1           White
4   1           Black
5   2           Metalic Red
6   2           Metalic Black
7   2           Metalic Blue
8   3           Classic Red
9   3           Classic Black
10  3           Classic Silver
```

I want to perform an operation with following criterias

```
IF available_colors.color LIKE '%Metalic Red%'

THEN return that "vehicle" with all the "available colors",
```

### as follows,

```
id  vehicle_name    color
--  ------------    ----- 
2   Yamaha FZ       Metalic Red
2   Yamaha FZ       Metalic Black
2   Yamaha FZ       Metalic Blue
```

Comment: `SELECT vehicles.id, vehicles.vehicle_name, available_colors.color FROM available_colors INNER JOIN vehicles ON vehicles.id = available_colors.vehicle_id WHERE available_colors.color LIKE '%Metalic Red%'`

Comment: @MarkBaker take a look at the required result - The OP wants **all** the colors for vehicle models that have a Metallic Red color available - this query would only return Metallic Red vehicles.

Comment: @Mark Baker: It won't return what is asked .

Comment: What is asked? `IF available_colors.color LIKE '%Metalic Red%'` is quite specific; but the `as follows` seems to contradict it.... is OP really asking for all colours to be returned for any vehicle that is available in metallic red?

Comment: "IF available_colors.color LIKE '%Metalic Red%'
THEN return that "vehicle" with all the "available colors","  and desired output gives me impression that all available colors have to be included in resultset if there is a record that satisfies "LIKE ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM vehicles V1 
JOIN  available_colors AC1 ON V1.id = AC1.vehicle_id
WHERE EXISTS 
( SELECT * FROM available_colors ac 
where ac.vehicle_id = v.id and ac.color like '%Metalic Red%')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this problem - the first is joining each vehicle with its corresponding colors. The second, is selecting only the vehicles that exist in Metallic Red:

```
SELECT        vehicles.id, vehicle_name, color
FROM          vehicles
JOIN          available_colors ON vehicles.id = available_colors.vehicle_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM   available_colors
              WHERE  color LIKE '%Metallic Red%' AND 
                     vehicles.id = available_colors.vehicle_id)
```

Comment: You do like making your queries overly complex and inefficient don't you

Answer (score 0):

Join both tables and try this:

```
select a.id, a.vehicle_name, b.color from vehicles a inner join available_colors b on 
a.id=b.vehicle_id where b.color like '%Metallic red%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this

```
Select v.vehicle_name,ac.color From vehicles v LEFT JOIN available_colors ac ON ac.vehicle_id = v.id WHERE ac.color LIKE %Metalic%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were willing to get the colors on a single row for each vehicle, you could do:

```
select v.id, v.vehicle_name, group_concat(ac.color) as colors
from vehicles v join
     available_colors ac
     on v.id = ac.vehicle_id
group by v.id, v.vehicle_name 
having sum(ac.color LIKE '%Metalic Red%) > 0;
```